# Facebook Feed Dialog - Post without a link

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-feed

I am trying to use the Facebook Feed Dialog to post a plain text message. According to the docs this should be possible by simply leaving the 'link' parameter empty'

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog

"The link attached to this post. With the Feed Dialog, people can also share plain text status updates with no content from your app; just leave the link parameter empty."

When doing this I successfully see the share dialog, but when I enter a message and click post I am receiving the following error:

```
Action Requires At Least One Reference: The action you're trying to publish 
is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least one 
of the following properties must be specified: object.
```

This is my code, if add a link, it works as expected.

```
FB.init({appId: APP_ID, status: true, cookie: true});

FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    title: "",
    link: "",
    caption: "",
    description: "",
    image: ""
}, function(response){});
```

Does anyone know how to successfully post a plain text message from the feed dialog?

Comment: what about all those parameters? title, caption, description and image do not exist for the feed dialog. and did you try removing the link parameter?

Comment: Yes, have tried with none of them, and each one individually with and without ‘link’ all give the same error unless link is populated.

Comment: then you should maybe just file a bug